# mysql whats wrong with these this query trying to join to Select statements

Tags: mysql

Here is the query trying to join to select statements! What am i doing wrong?

```
​SELECT u.user_id,c.c_id,u.username,u.email, u.user_pic_path,c.time, G.file_name
     FROM conversation c, users u
 LEFT OUTER JOIN gallery G 
 ON U.user_pic_path = G.img_id
     WHERE CASE 
     WHEN c.user_one =1
     THEN c.user_two = u.user_id
     WHEN c.user_two = 1
     THEN c.user_one= u.user_id
     END 
     AND (c.user_one =1 OR c.user_two = 1)
   JOIN(SELECT R.time
        FROM conversation_reply R 
        ORDER BY R.time DESC LIMIT 1)
        ON R.c_id_fk = c.c_id
```

First query where I Join 2 tables.

```
SELECT u.user_id,c.c_id,u.username,u.email, u.user_pic_path,c.time, G.file_name
         FROM conversation c, users u
     LEFT OUTER JOIN gallery G 
     ON U.user_pic_path = G.img_id
         WHERE CASE 
         WHEN c.user_one = '$user_one'
         THEN c.user_two = u.user_id
         WHEN c.user_two = '$user_one'
         THEN c.user_one= u.user_id
         END 
         AND (c.user_one ='$user_one' OR c.user_two ='$user_one')
         Order by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(C.time) DESC Limit 20";
```

Finally the secound simple query.

```
SELECT R.cr_id,R.time,R.reply 
                 FROM conversation_reply R 
                 WHERE R.c_id_fk = ?
                 ORDER BY R.cr_id DESC LIMIT 1"
```

Here is what i ended up with.

```
$sql = "SELECT u.user_id,c.c_id,u.username,u.email, u.user_pic_path,G.file_name, 
        MAX(r.time) last_reply_time,r.reply
FROM conversation c
JOIN users u ON
    CASE 
        WHEN c.user_one = 1
            THEN c.user_two = u.user_id
        WHEN c.user_two = 1
            THEN c.user_one= u.user_id
    END 
JOIN conversation_reply r ON c.c_id = r.c_id_fk
LEFT OUTER JOIN gallery G ON U.user_pic_path = G.img_id
WHERE (c.user_one = 1 OR c.user_two = 1)
GROUP BY c.c_id ORDER BY last_reply_time DESC";
```

The only thing is I get the very first conversation reply from the conversation not the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you join with a subquery, the alias has to go after the subquery, not after the table name inside the subquery.

```
JOIN(SELECT time, c_id_fk
    FROM conversation_reply 
    ORDER BY R.time DESC LIMIT 1) R
ON R.c_id_fk = c.c_id
```

But I'm not sure this will do what you want. This subquery finds the most recent reply across all conversations, not just conversations between the two users. If it's not a conversation by one of the two users, you'll get no results.

If you want to get the time of the most recent reply in that conversation, just do an ordinary `JOIN` with the `conversation_reply` and select `MAX(time)`.

```
SELECT u.user_id,c.c_id,u.username,u.email, u.user_pic_path,c.time, G.file_name, 
        MAX(r.time) last_reply_time
FROM conversation c
JOIN users u ON
    CASE 
        WHEN c.user_one =1
            THEN c.user_two = u.user_id
        WHEN c.user_two = 1
            THEN c.user_one= u.user_id
    END 
JOIN conversation_reply r ON c.id = r.c_id_fk
LEFT OUTER JOIN gallery G ON U.user_pic_path = G.img_id
WHERE (c.user_one =1 OR c.user_two = 1)
```

Comment: Very nice my friend. I will try this out. Exactly what i want. The most recent reply in a conversation. As of right now I'm "OK" with simple queries. What resources or books would you recommend for me to practice and master my sql skills.

Comment: I'm getting #1054 - Unknown column 'G.file_name' in 'field list'

Comment: Then I guess there's no `file_name` column in the `gallery` table. Look at your table schema to find the correct column name.

Comment: Did you use `G` or `g` as the alias for the `gallery` table? Case is significant.

Comment: I used G at this point i have tried everything. Even making sure it had no invisible characters, when i pasted it then manually typed it.

Comment: Works! just not when Try it only on phpMyAdmin.

Comment: IT ONLY GETS ONE RESULT